# Derivation of internal energy from an equation of state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am stuck in a thermodynamic problem. Say there is a gas of internal energy $u$ in a unit volume. Suppose the internal energy per unit volume, $u$, is only a function of temperature $T$, i.e. $u=u(T)$. Given the equation of state
$$p = \frac{1}{7}u(T),$$ where $p$ is the pressure of the gas, what is the functional form of $u(T)$?

Comment: Where did you get that  equation of state? I that a one seventh before u(T)?

Comment: yep. I guess the equation of state is purely arbitrary as it comes from my class exercises.

Comment: Is it supposed to be an ideal gas?

Comment: It is just a normal gas probably. If the gas is ideal, then the equation of state doesnt have much use.

Comment: Well, the equation you have written is certainly consistent with the ideal gas law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that it abides by the 'law of Joule' as the energy is only a function of the temperature, this is one of the 2 conditions for a system to be an ideal gas, if we assume this to be an ideal gas we could easily start from P=NkT with unit volume, N the amount of particles and k the constant of Boltzman and we would find $$u(T) = 7NkT$$ I'm not sure what you could do if isn't assumed to be an ideal gas as you don't know the dependency of the pressure on temperature other than to say that $u(T) = 7p(T)$.